# Is it possible / sensible to use external templating engine like dust.js or any other with anjularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dust.js

I had this urge to use dust.js templates as it provides a much better performance for UI rendering by caching the templates.

But in my current project we are using angularjs. It is even possible/sensible to use dust.js or any other templating engine with angular js ??

Even if i use dust.js will I lose the 2-way binding .. ?

Please suggest considering a relatively large SPA.. ?

P.S. I am a novice in both angular and dust.

Comment: AngularJS too caches the templates it uses. I believe in something like `$templateCache`.

Comment: ya angularjs caches it in $templateCache but as per my understanding its just to prevent the fetching of templates from the server. Does angularjs also provide something like pre-compiled templates ?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a good use case for a [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)!

Be aware that dust.js is an *asynchronous* renderer, but if you've [already loaded everything](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10407693/2770309) then dust will fire synchronously ([most of the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848851/is-it-possible-to-render-dust-js-templates-synchronously#comment20440019_10407693))

```
app.module('yours',[]).filter('dustRender', function(){
  return function(input, templateName){
    var rendered;
    dust.render(templateName, input, function(err, out){
      if('string' === typeof out){
        rendered = out;
      }
      err && console.error('Dust rendering error!', err);
    });
    return rendered || input;
  };
});
```

template

```
<span>{{ modelData | dustRender:'registered-dust-template' }}</span>
```

Note: Angular [$sanitize](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.$sanitize)s output, like html.

Comment: i dropped the idea of using the 2 together because I was losing the 2-way binding.. anyways +1 for the approach. U really gave me a nice insight into filters. Thanks