# Use dust templates with angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, dust.js

I am new to angularjs environment, I want to use angular using dust templates as the current application has dust templates but I could not find anything on how I can use my existing dust templates with angular js.

The problem is dust templates have different syntax while angular js templates use directives provided by it.

So the question is "Is there a way to use my existing dust templates with angular js"? Or I have to rewrite the templates according to angularjs specification.

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Did you try anything? Have you got some errors?

Comment: I donot know how to proceed.
I have a system that uses dust templates and backbone js now I need to transfer the system to angularjs but the problem is the existing templates are dust templates and what I have learned is angular uses html templates with its directives so the question is whether I have to rewrite the dust templates or to develop a parser or there is some existing functionality with angular that can be used. If you can suggest

Comment: My personal opinion is that it is bad to combine to many frameworks that does the same thing in the same application. This will make it hard for new eyes to understand the code, and it'll be hard for you to get help with the debug. 
Having backbone.js angular.js and dust.js with a little jquery.js might not be the best way to go.
If you got time, I would recommend you to port the dust to angular. or stick with dust

Comment: Hey thanks for the advise, My last resort would be to convert the files as there are about 100 or more templates that is why I am searching for something that can ease my work

Comment: AngularJS cannot use the DustJS templates on the front-end. You will need to re-write the templates for AngularJS.

Comment: Have to agree with @R.Gulbrandsen angular is already a template engine for frontend. When I build websites with angular I only use static gh-pages and a rest API. Its a good combo

Comment: [This post makes it appear feasible][1], with the possible caveat of Dust's async loading:


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21592671/1601926

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is one part that *could* work in most cases without much rewrite. I'm assuming you're using Dust and Angular defaults, so you'd need to replace the double curly braces with singles:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).config(function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{').endSymbol('}');
});
```

If you had simple use cases, like this in a template:

```
Hello Himanshu, the time is now {time}.
```

If you give Angular that file via templateUrl (or load it with gulp-angular-templatecache or whatever), you could do:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myTime', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.time = new Date();
});
```

This would render. But you'd have a lot of checking, renaming etc to do.

For more complex use cases, you'd have to do some renaming, search&replace etc. Example, if you had a simple loop, and wanted an ng-repeat in there, you'd have to replace:

```
<table name="users">
    {#users}
        <tr>
             <td>{name}</td>
        </tr>
    {/users}
</table>
```

with this:

```
<table name="users">
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
         <td>{user.name}</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Or if you had includes, change:

```
{>details}
```

to

```
<ng-include="details.html">
```

You can definitely reuse some of the components, but the question is how many and what you'd get. And I'm not sure how would other directives you might bring in react to the single-curly-brace use, they might break so you would probably be better off just search&replacing these too.

Ff course, rename them all to .html, .dust or similar, if they aren't named that.

Answer (score 3):

`AngularJS` cannot use the `DustJS` templates on the front-end. You will need to re-write the templates for `AngularJS`.

Having Said that, **If you are set on AngularJS:** 
you could check out [Angular-for-server](https://github.com/runvnc/angular-on-server), but it will still require re-writing DustJS templates.

**If you are still considering Frameworks:**
Check out [ReactJS](http://facebook.github.io/react/)

`ReactJS` allows for re-using templates both on the client and server. Also, it takes over the template on the front-end as well (for data-binding and event management). This is SEO friendly as it renders the first page on the Server itself.

**If you are set on DustJS templates:**
I am currently using `Dustjs` for development. One of the biggest hurdles I am facing is setting up `SPA` on the frontend. All the event management, routing and data-binding has to be done by the dev, once the page renders on the front-end for the first time. This gives me the advantage of using the same template on the client as well as server and also is SEO friendly due to first page rendering on the server itself.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others. I had similar problem with Handlebars. But migrating it to angular was easy. Benefits of this we're great. AngularJs has many usefull directives secondly-it corresponds with controller.

If you would like to use it anyway... Directives, controllers have template prop, you can insets template code there. But it must be angular friendly:) worked with handlebars for me. But after a while I decided to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

...or you can just compile the curly brackets for the Angular templates, something like:

```
{~lb}{~lb} slide.text{~rb}{~rb}
```

[Issue in the repo of Krakenjs where the solution is commented.](https://github.com/krakenjs/kraken-js/issues/85)
[Section in Dust.js tutorial](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial#More_on_Dust_Output_and_Dust_Filters)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution possible to this issue. Simply ensure you leave a space after the first double braces and dust will ignore and angular will pick it up.

```
{{variable + func() + 'etc'}} // Dust will process to {}
{{ variable + func() + 'etc'}} // Angular will process
```